# CDM to doctrine mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations

I'd like to map with Doctrine ORM 2 the following CDM:

[image: CDM model]

The story behind it:
An account (compte) may have 0 to 1 parent and have 0 to n children.

so far I've found only one link to help me:
[doctrine tuto](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing)

But it's incomplete and I don't think it adresses my issue.

edit: I only want help to map the two associations parent-children

this is the code I got so far

```
class Account
{
    /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique = true)
 */

protected $name;  

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */

protected $code;

 /**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="id")
 */

private  $children;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="id")
 */

private $parent;
}
```

Comment: in how far is the tutorial incomplete? you don't know how to integrate the mapping with symfony2? what exactly do you need - the mapping only? the classes? CRUD? please be a bit more precise ..

Comment: I know how to do the class "Account" and properties etc. I know how to CRUD. I'm just not sure how to map the two "foreign" keys:
I guess it's OnetoMany parent owning for the parent side and manytomany children owning for the child relation.

But that's a wild guess. An this is quite hard to test..